# How to avoid duplicate records in SQL server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, duplicates

I have a C# assignment which states that I have to avoid duplicate records in SQL Server Explorer. Duplicate records can occur when the user inserts a name that already exists. I am using a table called "Move" and it has four columns: id, name, description, sweatrate.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s/`UNIQUE INDEX`es.

Comment: @Larnu

What should I do with this?

Comment: It is odd that you start with "I have a C# assignment' and then immediately refer to SSMS. What is your actual assignment? To write application code using C# to avoid duplicates during insertion in some fashion? Or is this a database design question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Design view of your table (right click it):

[image]

Right click somewhere and choose Indexes/Keys:

[image]

Add an index, set the Columns to Name

[image]

Set it Unique

[image]

Maybe give it a nice name like UIX_Move__Name

Hit Close/Save etc..

It's now impossible to insert duplicate names:

[image]

Case sensitivity depends on the collation applicable

Comment: "Impossible" meaning: you'll get an exception if you try to.

Comment: @CAIUS_Jard : UNIQUE depends also of the collation semantic. If the collation is CS (Case Sensitive) then your second insert will not fail...

Comment: True, hence the ultimate sentence of the answer ;)